# Python locking threads not working in an example

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, locking

I am trying to grasp the `Lock` in `multithreading` module in python. But for some reason it is not locking the objects and lets the next thread run without waiting for the lock to release.

Here is the code:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time

database_value = 0


def increase(lock):
    global database_value
    lock.acquire()

    local_copy = database_value
    local_copy += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)

    database_value = local_copy
    lock.release()
    




if __name__ == '__main__':

    lock = Lock()
    print('start value',database_value)

    thread1 = Thread(target =increase, args = (lock,))
    thread2 = Thread(target =increase, args = (lock,))
    
    print('start')
    #start
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    #join 
    print('join')
    thread1.join()
    thread1.join()

    print('end value', database_value)
```

The Output I am expecting is:

```
start value 0
start
join
end value 2
```

But the Output I get:

```
start value 0
start
join
end value 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the join step, you wait for thread1 instead of thread2.

```
#join 
    print('join')
    thread1.join()
    thread1.join() # Should be thread2
```

If you change it below, it will work.

```
#join 
    print('join')
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
```